# Creating custom user roles in ASP.NET MVC and Azure AD

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC application that uses Azure AD auth out-of-the-box.

What I want to do is define custom roles for certain users. For example, mark `JohnDoe@contoso` as a `"Portal Admin"` or `SarahJones@contoso` as a `"Site Manager"` - I want to do that without messing with AD roles, since I don't have full access to the AD internals.

I am fine deploying a custom DB to contain the roles. Is there a generic solution for this or do I have to implement my custom verification layer?

---

**Update 1:** I can deploy a [custom role provider](http://kitsula.com/Article/Custom-Role-Provider-for-MVC) and connect it to a different DB, but am wondering if there is a more straightforward way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Azure Web Apps, which supports ASP.NET MVC then you can use the Azure Active Directory authentication mechanism. Here is a blog post describing how to set it up:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication/

Once you have that, auth will be enabled for your app and you can configure the AAD app in the portal. See this blog post for more details:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2014/12/18/azure-active-directory-now-with-group-claims-and-application-roles.aspx

To modify the permission levels, you should be able to use role claims. See this example for guidance:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims

Accessing the manifest:

[image]

Comment: So the first two parts are working. Regarding group claims, I need to find a way to abstract that out and implement it without touching AAD permissions or existing AAD groups. Is there a generic way to do that?

Comment: I believe you should be able to use role claims if you do not have access to group claims.

Comment: Essentially, I am stuck implementing a custom role provider. Thanks for confirming.